# Floating Labels Custom

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to move up a little more the Floating Labels?

My Edit Text actually has a borderline or a frame, but when the hint floats it floats over the borderline.

Can anyone help me?
Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes There is a work around of this problem. Use

```
android:translationY="10dp"
```

to your EditText

Answer (score 0):

use this textinputlayout,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/username_text_input_layout"
                                    style="@style/TextLabel"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                    <EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/etUsername"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                        android:ems="10"
                                        android:hint="Username"
                                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                                        android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
                                        android:maxLength="255"
                                        android:singleLine="true" />

                                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

you can use this style , set font as you need , **edit this as per your need** .

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Error">
            <!--//hint color And Label Color in False State-->
            <!--<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorPrimary</item>-->
            <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_normal_size</item>
            <!--//Label color in True State And Bar Color False And True State-->
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <!--<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/</item>
            <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/Color Name</item>-->
        </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have definitely problems with `android:padding`. I don't see your code, but you may put them in wrong places.

Delete them first and let me know if problem still happening:

Here is an sample code from [Android Material Design Floating Labels for EditText](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-floating-labels-for-edittext/) tutorial

> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
>
>     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
>         android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
>         app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
>         app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
> </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:paddingLeft="20dp"
>     android:paddingRight="20dp"
>     android:paddingTop="60dp">
>
>     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
>         android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>         <EditText
>             android:id="@+id/input_name"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:singleLine="true"
>             android:hint="@string/hint_name" />
>     </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
>
>     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
>         android:id="@+id/input_layout_email"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>         <EditText
>             android:id="@+id/input_email"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
>             android:hint="@string/hint_email" />
>     </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
>
>     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
>         android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>         <EditText
>             android:id="@+id/input_password"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:inputType="textPassword"
>             android:hint="@string/hint_password" />
>     </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
>
>     <Button android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="@string/btn_sign_up"
>         android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
>         android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
>         android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
>
> </LinearLayout>   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
> ```

Also look at another great example to learn how it should be implemented from [Google Samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/sign_in_username.xml) Github Repository

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

try adjusting

```
android:paddingTop=""
android:paddingBottom=""
```

property of Floating Labels

Answer (score 0):

```
        enter code here
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstnameLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstname_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="First Name"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_person_black_18dp"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:textColorHint="#693EB4" />
       </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Try this maybe it will help you.